# typescript: state an interface property is defined if another property matches a condition

Tags: typescript

I'm declaring an interface that wraps string data obtained from a TCP socket. The `status` property denotes the current status of obtaining the data. It's set to `pending` if the request was sent but a response hasn't been received yet, `failure` if an error was returned, and `success` if a complete response was returned.

```
interface TCPData {
  data?: string
  status: 'success' | 'pending' | 'failure'
}
```

Thus, I know that `this.data` is guaranteed to not be undefined if `this.status === 'success'`. The problem is that now, whenever I want to access the data, I still always have to typecheck `this.data` because I declared it as `string | undefined`.

```
const tcp_data: DataInterface = readTCPData()
if (tcp_data.status === 'success') {
  console.log(tcp_data.data) // <<< type error: data could be undefined
}
```

Is there any way for me to declare that if one property matches a certain condition (e.g. `this.status === 'success'`), then another property (e.g. `this.data`) is guaranteed to not be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `type` and alternate between the two possible shapes:

```
type TCPData = {
  data: string
  status: 'success'
} | {
  data?: string // or maybe remove this completely?
  status: 'pending' | 'failure'
}
```

Comment: that's crazy. i searched the documentation for 'type unions' and the example literally exactly describes my scenario... how embarassing lol. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions